# CentOS7: Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

Tags: ssl, docker, centos7, openshift-origin

I've installed Docker on CentOS7, now I try to launch the server in a Docker container.

```
 $ docker run -d --name "openshift-origin" --net=host --privileged \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /tmp/openshift:/tmp/openshift \
openshift/origin start
```

This is the output:

```
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/containers/create?name=openshift-origin: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I have tried the same command with `sudo` and that works fine (I can also run images in OpenShift bash etc.) But it feels wrong to use it, am I right? What is a solution to let is work as normal user?

Docker is running (`sudo service docker start`). Restarting the CentOS did not help.

Comment: OpenShift in a container needs to use the docker socket, which in recent fedora/centos installations requires root (because the docker daemon can do *anything* on your host).  As the other commenter noted you can do a number of things not to require root to call docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is:

```
/var/run/docker.sock: permission denied.
```

That seems pretty clear: the permissions on the Docker socket at `/var/run/docker.sock` do not permit you to access it. This is reasonably common, because handing someone acccess to the Docker API is effectively the same as giving them `sudo` privileges, but without any sort of auditing.

If you are the only person using your system, you can:

- Create a `docker` group or similar if one does not already exist.
- Make yourself a member of the `docker` group
- Modify the startup configuration of the `docker` daemon to make the socket owned by that group by adding `-G docker` to the options.  You'll probably want to edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to make this change, unless it's already configured that way.

With these changes in place, you should be able to access docker from your user account with requiring `sudo`.